# How to create a list of objects for each time the for loop hits?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Okay, so this may be a lengthy one but currently I'm stuck on how to create a list of Ingrediants in this case for each new recipe, because when I run these two programs as of now It continually adds objects to the same list. Any advice in shortening the code or better ways would be appreciated, but making a sort of instance variable for each iteration is top priority. thanks. To clarify, I need for each time I run the AddRecipe Class a new list of ingrediants specific to that recipe, and not a large list of Ingrediants from all the recipes.

Problem; For each time i iterate through my addIngrediant class, I want to have a distinct ingrediant value for the AddRecipe class that uses it. (For every recipe, new Ingrediants) I'm not sure how to do this, and have provided a sample of both methods.

In Recipe Class

```
  public static void addIngrediants(String EcipeName){
  if(Recipe.recipeName.equals(EcipeName)){
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

System.out.println("Would you like to add an Ingrediant(YES or NO)");
Scanner yesSir = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputSir = yesSir.nextLine();

if(inputSir.equals("YES")){
System.out.println("Enter your Ingrediant; ");
String userIngred = yesSir.nextLine();
Ingred.add(userIngred);

System.out.println("Your Ingrediant is; " + userIngred);
System.out.println("Your new ingrediant list is now; " + Ingred);

    }
else{
    System.out.println("Okay thanks!");
    break;
}
}
}


}
```

In Wrapper Class

```
    public static void AddRecipe(){
    Recipe jackson = new Recipe();
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<= recipeBook.size();){
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Recipe Book!");
        System.out.println("============================");
        jackson.getDirections();
        jackson.getCalorieCount();
        jackson.getHi();
        jackson.getRecipeName();



            System.out.println("Would you like to add a recipe?(Type YES or NO)");
            Scanner wantTo = new Scanner(System.in);
            String bad = wantTo.nextLine();

            if(bad.equals("YES")){
                index++;
                System.out.println("Great, now lets name your Recipe;");
                String yesName = wantTo.nextLine();
                jackson.setRecipeName(yesName);

                System.out.println("First we'll start with Ingrediants, Input as many as you like");
                Recipe.addIngrediants(yesName);



                System.out.println("Moving on, Input your Directions;");
                String bud = wantTo.nextLine();
                jackson.setDirections(bud);

                System.out.println("Now input a Calorie Count (Numbers Only!)");
                int jman = wantTo.nextInt();
                jackson.setCalorieCount(jman);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I voted to close because: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: I thought I was very clear with the problem, but I'll edit it in if it wasn't noticable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem.  Just from looking at the little bit of code you posted it would seem to me that you are not really embracing an object oriented design.  From reading over your problem I would suggest making a recipe class that will store all fundamental elements of a recipe.  In here you should have an instance variable that will store your list of steps.  From here I would make another class that will act as a recipe book.  This class should be able to create, store and manage recipe objects.  The last class I would create would be a class that can take user input.  This would be the highest level class in your program and would allow the user to actually use the program via console input.

Comment: That is what I have, only showed part of the class for simplicity. My error is that I can't store individual lists of Ingrediants for each new Recipe.

Comment: Each recipe should have it's own unique list, if that list is a part of the recipe class (assuming that list is not static) each time you make a new recipe object that list should be empty.  Also, from just looking at what you posted your program is not what I described.  Your recipe class should not be asking for names and such, it should only be used for storing and retrieving information.

Comment: Ok thanks, and if its static what would that change? If you have time could you show me a coded example of the recipe class? ((Sorry for my lack of knowledge, 2 months into computer science))

Comment: The static identifier basically tells java that only a single one will exits between all objects of a particular class.  This would be useful for things like  a counter, if you needed to know how many of a particular object were being made.  I will not write the code for your recipe class, this could be a good opportunity for you to learn something.  Just try to stick everything that is fundamental about a recipe into a single class.  Have getters and setters for all your variables.  Then have another class with an array that can instantiate and store these recipe objects.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. I'd give you some rep if I was above 15!

Comment: No problem man!  Just keep coding and study up on the fundamentals of object oriented programming and design and these problems become really easy to solve.